# Laravel form checkbox checked flag not working correctly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a piece of template:

```
@foreach ( Permission::all() as $permission )
    {{ Form::checkbox('permissions[]', $permission->id, $role->permissions->contains($permission->id) ) }} <label>{{ $permission->label }}</label>
    {{ var_dump($role->permissions->contains($permission->id)) }}
@endforeach
```

this outputs the following html:

```
<input checked="checked" name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" value="1"> <label>View entity</label>
<small>boolean</small> true
<input checked="checked" name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" value="3"> <label>Edit Entity</label>
<small>boolean</small> true
<input checked="checked" name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" value="4"> <label>Delete entity</label>
<small>boolean</small> false
```

W T H is going on. anyone any ideas?

**EDIT**
even moreconfusion. If I pass in `false` to the Form::checkbox function. Only the first item is rendered without the checked parameter. I give up :(

Comment: This are the parameters accepted by `Form::checkbox()`, `{{ Form::checkbox(name, value, [boolean true or false - this is optional], [an array of options - this is optional])}}`

Comment: If I use `Form::checkbox()`, it will be checked no matter what, even if I use false in the third parameter. Just stick with plain html for now.

Comment: @user2094178 ,  I have managed to make the third option work.

Comment: @lozadaOmr Doesn't work here

Comment: @Pinoniq What does ` $role->permissions->contains($permission->id)` return, because I think requires a boolean value, either true or false. I don't have your whole code, but tested it right now passing the 3rd parameters as true will render the checkbox as checked, while false will render it unchecked.

Comment: @lozadaOmr check my code in the question ;) That is what my var_dump returns... Boolean (true / false) See myy Issue to know what was going on. Laravel checked internally or permissions was part of the object (and it is) thus always transforming my false to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the 'problem'. See this issue on github: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5078 :

my model being parsed has the permissions() array. The false will be ignored and the checkbox will be shown checked. Even if the $permission->id is not related to the Role.
FormBuilder@getCheckboxCheckedState

`return is_array($posted) ? in_array($value, $posted) : (bool) $posted;`

this line will return true, even if the $permission->id is set. Or the 'checked state' parameter is given.

Perosnally I think that all those isChecked checks should only be performed if $checked is_null.

FormBuilder@checkable()

`$checked = $this->getCheckedState($type, $name, $value, $checked);`

should be

`if ( is_null($checked) ) $checked = $this->getCheckedState($type, $name, $value, $checked);`